# Monolithic Methods - Disadvantages

Tags: methods, api-design

Let's say I am creating a MATH class and need to provide a method to process two numbers. [

Instead of providing the traditional mechanism of have methods for each possible operation I provide a single method eval: `float eval(ArgObj);`  where `ArgObj` is an object which can hold two numbers and an operator. Thus now with a single method I can do multiple operations.

What are the disadvantages of this design?

Two certain disadvantages are maintenance and documentation as eval get the ability to process more operations.

What are the other disadvantages that I am missing out here?

Update: 
What I am trying to figure out are negatives of a large monolithic method, the above example is just hypothetical another similar example would be a method like

`float doSomething(int basedOn)`

where doSomething can do a bunch of operations.

Comment: Casting and identifying what the *ArgObj* actually is will definitely be a huge problem. What about overloads?

Comment: @PiotrJustyna True, just updated up question too, with the first example your point is very valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading code should be a pleasurable experience, knowing what a method does should be blatantly obvious.

Would you also like to reduce the English language to 10 words? Of course not...

Learn from well-used and well-loved APIs, and ensure your API is easy to learn, easy to use, and difficult to misuse.

I would suggest `doSomething` doesn't come close. What happens when you need a different action, do you call the new method `doSomething2`? Hopefully, you don't see that as a viable option...

Comment: Don't be silly. Obviously the new method should be called `doSomethingElse`.

Comment: Or even dse? :)